# Computing the molar volume for a 2D-simulation of phase separation

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, computational-chemistry, glass

I am a mathematician and I want to simulate phase separation that occurs in a sodium silicate glass ($12.5\,\text{Na}_2\text{O}\cdot 87.5\,\text{SiO}_2$) at $T = 923\ \text{K}$ as it was done, for example, in [Kim and Sanders (2020)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022309319304624).

In particular, I want to do this simulation in **two-dimensions**. However, certain parameters that are implicitly required for the Cahn-Hilliard equation are only given in units that concern 3D simulations. For example, the molar volume for the mixture above can be computed to be
\begin{equation}
V_m = 25.13 \cdot 10^{-6}\ \frac{\text{m}^3}{\text{mol}}.
\end{equation}

**Question:** How do I have to deal with that in a 2D simulation? From a geometrical point of view, I just would like to consider
\begin{equation}
(25.13 \cdot 10^{-6})^{\frac{2}{3}}
\end{equation}
as a corresponding quantity for a **two-dimensional** simulation (unit: $\frac{\text{m}^2}{\text{mol}^{(2/3)}}$ ?). The quantity **mol** refers basically to a  3D framework, isn't it?

Comment: Define relation between molar volume and molar area. [m2/mol]

Comment: My proposal simply comes from the geometric average but actually does not fit toe the notion of a mol. I still think that the notion of a mol is meat for 3D. Therefore, I have no idea how to deal with that notion in 2D.

Comment: At least to me, "molar area" is not that common. And I have also no idea how to compute this quantity (without the corresponding mass density).

Comment: Computing such things in 2D is not common either. You have to use 2D variants of 3D quantities. Similarly, density in kg/m3 would have 2D variant area density in kg/m2.

Comment: Actually, in most cases simulations (especially simulating phase separations) start with 2D simulations. One paper is cited in the questions. [Here is another one](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/34095939/). And I was wondering where I can find the corresponding 2D parameter variants or how these 2D variants are computed.

Comment: I am not saying 2D models are unusual. I have just said by other words, that 2D volume is area. Twice molar volume means twice molar area. The only problem is the proportionality constant.

Answer (score 2):

Since one really wants to have the quantity (molar area) in the unit area per mole (and not per $\text{mol}^{\frac{2}{3}}$), the guessed solution $(25.13 \cdot 10^{-6})^{\frac{2}{3}}$ above is in fact not what we are looking for. Instead, it seems to be common to compute
\begin{equation}
A_m = \left(\frac{V_m}{N_A}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}} \cdot N_A = V_m^{\frac{2}{3}} \cdot N_A^{\frac{1}{3}},
\end{equation}
where $N_A = 6.02 \cdot 10^{23}$ is the Avogadro constant.